# elasticsearch synonyms analyzer gives 0 results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am using `elasticsearch 7.0.0`.

I am trying to work on `synonyms` with this configuration while creating `index`.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "address.state": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "synonym"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a document inserted into the index:

```
{
  "name": "Berry's Burritos",
  "description": "Best burritos in New York",
  "address": {
    "street": "230 W 4th St",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "zip": "10014"
  },
  "location": [
    40.7543385,
    -73.976313
  ],
  "tags": [
    "mexican",
    "tacos",
    "burritos"
  ],
  "rating": "4.3"
}
```

Also content in `synonyms.txt`:

```
ny, new york, big apple
```

When I tried searching for anything in `address.state` property, I get `empty` result.

Here's the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "rating": {
            "gte": 4
          }
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "address.state": "ny"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Even with `ny` (as it is:no synonym) in query, the result is empty.

Before, when I created index without `mappings`, the query used to give the result, only except for synonyms.

But now with `mappings`, the result is empty even though the term is present.

This query is working though:
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "tacos",
      "fields": [
        "tags"
      ]
    }
  }
}

I looked and researched into many articles/tutorials and came up this far.

What am I missing here now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While indexing you are passing the value as `"state":"NY"`. Notice the case of `NY`. The analyzer `synonym` define in the settings has only one filter i.e. `synonym`. `NY` doesn't match any set of synonyms in defined in synonym.txt due to case. NOTE that `NY` isn't equal to `ny`. To overcome this problem (or we can call making it case insensitive) add `lowercase` filter before `synonym` filter to `synonym` analyzer. This will ensure that any input text is lower cased first and then synonym filter is applied. Same will happen when you search on that field using full text search queries.

So you settings will be as below:

```
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

No changes are required in mapping.

#### Why it initially worked?

Answer to this is because when you haven't defined any mapping, elastic would map `address.state` as a `text` field with no explicit analyzer defined for the field. In such case elasticsearch by default uses [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition) which uses lowercase token filter as one of the filters. and hence the query matched the document.

Comment: thank you for that explanation.. being a rookie to `elasticsearch`, your answer really help me a lot..

Comment: Glad it helped.